# How to dim entire screen except for region between two concentric squares using pure javascript and css (no jquery)

Tags: javascript, css

I know this is a frequently asked question and I have looked at many related questions/answers, still I am not able to get it to work. I want to dim the entire screen except for certain portions. in one case the portion that should not be dimmed is the region **between** two concentric squares. I want a solution that uses only javascript and css. It should not use any 3rd party library like jquery. I am not worried about old browsers. As long as it works on latest browsers I am okay with whatever css3 it needs. Some other restrictions I have - I am using absolute positioning in my app. All elements are absolutely positioned.

**EDIT:** thanks for helping me with you answers. I think I should have mentioned I want to dim the screen in response to an event like user clicking on a button. That event dims the screen except for certain areas that I want to highlight. When user clicks on the button again, the screen is restored. When the screen is dimmed user should not be able to do any interaction with DOM elements in the dimmed regions.

This is my js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z1Lj7h90/

**HTML**:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="outer"></div>
    <div id="inner"></div>
    <button id="mybutton">Highlight</button>
    <div id="darkness"></div>    
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#mybutton
{
position: absolute; top: 450px; left:100px; z-index:10;
}

#main {
    position: relative;
    z-index:10;   
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#darkness
{
    z-index:5;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.fadein
{   
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

#outer
{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    border:2px solid red;
}

#inner
{
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    left:40px;
    width:340px;
    height:340px;
    border:2px solid blue;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var button = document.getElementById("mybutton");
button.addEventListener("click", toggle);
var ff = false;
function toggle()
{ 
    var darkness = document.getElementById("darkness");
  darkness.classList.toggle("fadein");
    if (ff)
    {
        dice.style.zIndex = originalZIndex;
        button.innerText = "Highlight";
    }
    else
    {
        dice.style.zIndex = 10;
        button.innerText = "Restore";
    }
    ff = !ff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with CSS.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-color: #999999;
}

#outer{ 
  position: absolute; 
  width: 200px; 
  height: 200px; 
  top: 50%; 
  left: 50%; 
  margin-left: -50px; 
  margin-top: -50px;
  background-color: #44c;
}

#inner{ 
  position: relative; 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px; 
  top: 50%; 
  left: 50%; 
  margin-left: -50px; 
  margin-top: -50px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

a solution in css whit five div..
I assume that the internal square is #q5 and you have a spacebetween of 20px; all other measures can be calculated.

```
<div id="q1" class="obscure">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="q2" class="obscure">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="q3" class="obscure">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="q4" class="obscure">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="q5" class="obscure">&nbsp;</div>
```

now, q1 is at north, and q3 is at south; q2 and q4 lateral

```
#q5 { 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px;
    left: 50px;  
    top: 120px;
}

#q4{
    left:0px;
    width: 30px; /* #q5.left - spacebetween; ex: spacebetween=20 */
    top: 0px; bottom: 0px; 
}
#q2{
    left: 170px; /* #q5.width + 2*spacebetween + q5.width;  */
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px; bottom: 0px; 
}
#q1{
    left: 30px; /* width of q4*/
    top: 0px;
    height: 100px; /*q5.top - spacebettween*/     
    width: 140px; /* q5.width + 2*spacebetween */
}
#q3{
    left: 30px;   /* width of q4*/
    width: 140px; /* q5.width + 2*spacebetween*/
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 240px; /*q5.height + q5.top + spacebettween */     
}
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/alemarch/czpksfdd/ for detail.
A more generic solution is simple implementing in js the formulas in my css comment

Comment: Alessandro thanks for your solution. You definitely put lot of time in it. I am studying your solution. In my application, the regions I want to highlight will change from time to time. Basically I am developing a single page architecture javascript game in which there will be a help button that user can click to get help at any time. Depending on the game state, different regions of the screen may need to be dimmed. I will study your solution, but it does not look very flexible just from looking at it. **If you look at my fiddle, is there any way to highlight region between squares.**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/alemarch/czpksfdd/10/
You only call obscureWith2Square with 4 number internal and external size, left and right of the internal square. #content can be your tag body and #something your body content I think there isn't a simple way only with 2 square..maybe you can use transparent png